# tcolorbox: how do I align on the baseline of the title

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to the two boxes titled `personal` and `other` to appear on the same line and to be aligned on the baseline of the title.  So far, I can't even get them on the same line even though there seems to be plenty of room for them.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}


  \rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

  \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth]{{personal}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%
  \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth]{{other}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

I've now managed to get the boxes on the same line by using the `before=,after=` keys.

[image]

But they're still not aligned as I wish to have them aligned.

I can achieve the effect that I desire by creating a strut and embedding the two `tcolorbox` environments within a `tikzpicture`:

```
  \def\aes{\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{3ex}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west]
         at (0,0) {%%
          \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth]{{\aes personal}}
           These are the menu items:
           \begin{itemize}
           \item 
           \item 
           \item 
           \item 
           \item 
           \end{itemize}
          \end{mybox}%%
          };

    \node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west]
       at (0.5\columnwidth,0) {%%
          \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth]{{\aes other}}
           These are the menu items:
           \begin{itemize}
           \item 
           \item 
           \item 
           \end{itemize}
          \end{mybox}%%
       };

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

but it seems that there's got to be a more *natural* way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use the `adjustbox` package and apply:

```
before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup, after=\egroup
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you don't want the two boxes separate horizontally, remove the `\hfill`.
- Since the depth of the titles in the two boxes varied, I added a `\vphantom{p}` to the second box's title.

### References:

- This is "adapted" from [Vertical alignment of "nobeforeafter" tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180520/vertical-alignment-of-nobeforeafter-tcolorbox).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}


  \rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

  \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth, before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup,
  after=\egroup\hfill]{{personal}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%
  \begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth, before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup,
  after=\egroup]{{other\vphantom{p}}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: While I went with a different approach, I appreciated how your answer stuck with a `tcolorbox` approach.  I never would have thought to use the `before` and `after` keys in this manner.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I like the `adjustbox` answer since this provides an elegant way to marry the various `adjustbox` features with `tcolorbox`.

**Updated answer:**

If it's just for top alignment: `tcolorbox 3.30 (2014/11/17)` and above has several alignment and spacing features which are useful here. The first solution uses `box align=top` to top-align the boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}

\rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth,box align=top,before=\par,after=\hfill]{personal}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}%%
\begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth,box align=top,before=,after=\par]{other}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result is achieved using the `raster` library. Here, the two boxes are encapsulated in a `tcbraster` environment which cares for width and spacing automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}

\rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster column skip=0.1\columnwidth,raster valign=top]
\begin{mybox}{personal}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{other}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Another possibilty is to use the `raster equal height` feature which does not look bad in my eyes for the given application. The two boxes are getting the same height after two compilations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}

\rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster column skip=0.1\columnwidth,raster equal height]
\begin{mybox}{personal}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{other}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll look forward to the added feature.

Comment: @A.Ellett `tcolorbox 3.30` is out now. I've updated my answer using the new features.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always stick them in top-aligned `minipages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
%  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2ex,xshift=4ex},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, 
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
%  boxed title style={
%    boxrule=0pt,
%    colframe=white,
%    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{hello world}
  this is a test
\end{mybox}


  \rule{0.45\columnwidth}{2pt}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{mybox}[width=0.9\columnwidth]{{personal}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{mybox}[width=0.9\columnwidth]{{other}}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item 
   \item 
   \item 
   \end{itemize}
  \end{mybox}%%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this idea if only simply because something similar occurred to me.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is not quite kosher, but ultimately I dispensed with using `tcolorbox` (given that my question is about using `tcolorbox`).  I kept running into too many headaches to get things to work the way I would like.  But, I'll continue in the future to explore this package and become better acquainted with its possibilities.

What I wound up doing though was to just build my boxes up from the ground within `tikz` where I'm a bit more familiar.  (It hadn't occurred to me to use this approach until I wound up embedding my two `tcolorbox`s within a `tikzpicture`.)

Additionally, I noticed that it wasn't the baseline of the title that I wanted to align on, but rather the top of the frame surrounding the boxed content.

This could be cleaned up a bit.  But, overall, what I'm trying to do is rather simple:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@mybox@width{3in}
\def\ae@mybox@title{}
\pgfkeys{/ae/mybox/.cd,
  width/.store in=\ae@mybox@width,
  title/.store in=\ae@mybox@title,
}

\newsavebox\ae@mybox

\newenvironment{mybox}[1][]
  {\pgfkeys{/ae/mybox/.cd,#1}%%
   \begin{lrbox}{\ae@mybox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\ae@mybox@width}
  }
  {
    \end{minipage}%%
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(title.west)]
      \node[outer sep=0pt,
            anchor=north west,
            inner sep=8pt] (MP)    at (0,0)                         {\usebox{\ae@mybox}};
      \node[anchor=west]   (title) at ($(MP.north west)+(1em,2ex)$) {\ae@mybox@title};
      \draw [rounded corners]
          (title.west) -- (MP.west |- title.west) 
                       -- (MP.south west)
                       -- (MP.south east)
                       -- (MP.north east|-title.east)
                       -- (title.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[width=\dimexpr0.45\columnwidth-16pt,title=personal]
 These are the menu items:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item 
 \item 
 \item 
 \item 
 \item 
 \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}%%
\hspace{\fill}%%
\begin{mybox}[width=0.45\columnwidth-16pt,title=other]
 These are the menu items:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item 
 \item 
 \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reading your answer I discovered that there are "kosher" and "non-kosher" ways in LaTeX :-)