# Object-Z state schema notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, line

I'm trying to achieve something like the following with LaTeX:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myframe}[2][]{%
  enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black,coltitle=black,
  sharp corners,boxrule=0.4pt,
  fonttitle=\itshape,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.4\baselineskip-0.4pt,xshift=2ex},
  boxed title style={tile,size=minimal,left=0.5mm,right=1mm,
    colback=white,before upper=\strut},
  title=#2,#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}{Pop}
  \begin{myframe}{Push}
    Some sample text here that's in the box.
  \end{myframe}
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried referring to other threads like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210928/tcolorbox-how-do-i-align-on-the-baseline-of-the-title) but I am having trouble piecing everything together; I'm mostly struggling with the horizontal line between the variable declarations and premises sections as well as the nesting of boxes. What would be the best way to construct this? Thanks!

Comment: This is typically something you could be able to achieve with `tcolorbox`. Did you try something? If so, please share your code and we'll be able to help you out. You would have more response if you offer something to work with instead of asking for something from scratch.

Comment: hi @SebGlav, you are right, I did try something with `tcolorbox`, I have also added my previous attempt to the post. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package [`objectz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/objectz) is quite old but seems to work well with a modern LaTeX. I know nothing about this language (notation,...?) so I may be using the wrong semantic markup, but if you know the language then you can correct the environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oz}

\begin{document}

\begin{class}{Buffer}
\also
\sres (max,\Init,Join,Leave) \\
\begin{state}
max: \nat \\
items: \seq MSG
\ST
\# items \leq max
\end{state} \\
\begin{init}
items = \emptyseq
\end{init} \\
\begin{sidebyside}
\begin{schema}{Join}
\Delta(items) \\
msg?: MSG
\ST
\# items < max \\
items' = items \cat \lseq msg?\rseq
\end{schema}
\nextside
\begin{schema}{Leave}
\Delta(items) \\
msg!: MSG
\ST
item \neq \emptyseq \\
items = \lseq msg!\rseq \cat items'
\end{schema}
\end{sidebyside}
\end{class}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's the one :) I guess I could have found that on CTAN myself using the title of this question... @Peter you should move the accepted answer to this one, as it is clearly preferable to use this package than to fiddle around with spaces and `\hskip`s.

Comment: Used this package in the past and it was very good. Object-Z is a formal specification language used in high integrity computing, for those who are wondering.

Comment: wow I didn't know there was a native package for this notation. moved this post to the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution with `tcolorbox`. As it uses nested boxes, it won't be breakable between pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    size=title,
    fontupper=\itshape, fonttitle=\itshape,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white, colframe=black, coltitle=black,
    boxrule=1pt, rightrule=0pt,
    segmentation code={\draw (segmentation.west)--++(0:.25\textwidth);},
    attach boxed title to top text left={yshift*=-2mm},
    boxed title style={size=fbox, colback=white, frame hidden},
    #1
}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[title={Buffer}]
$\upharpoonright$(max, \textsc{Init}, Join, Leave)
\begin{mybox}
max : $\mathbb{N}$\\
$items:seq\ MSG$
\tcblower
\#items $\leqslant$ max
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[title={\textsc{Init}}]
items $=\langle\ \rangle$
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[nobeforeafter, width=.48\textwidth, title={Join}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg? : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $<$ max\\
items' = items$\overset{\smallfrown}{ }\langle$ msg? $\rangle$  
\end{mybox}\hfill
\begin{mybox}[nobeforeafter, width=.48\textwidth, title={Leave}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg! : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $\ne \langle \rangle$\\
items $= \langle\text{msg!}\rangle\overset{\smallfrown}{ }$items'  
\end{mybox}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

In case that a brekable solution is necessary, an alternative to nested boxes could be a `boxedraster` (or `boxeditemize`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    mybox/.style={%
        enhanced,
        size=title,
        fontupper=\itshape, fonttitle=\itshape,
        sharp corners,
        colback=white, colframe=black, coltitle=black,
        boxrule=1pt, rightrule=0pt,
        segmentation code={\draw (segmentation.west)--++(0:.25\textwidth);},
        attach boxed title to top text left={yshift*=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=fbox, colback=white, frame hidden},
    }
}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, mybox]{mybox, breakable, title={Buffer}}
%
\tcbitem[blank, raster multicolumn=2] $\upharpoonright$(max, \textsc{Init}, Join, Leave)
%
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] 
max : $\mathbb{N}$\\
$items:seq\ MSG$
\tcblower
\#items $\leqslant$ max
%
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, title={\textsc{Init}}] items $=\langle\ \rangle$
%
\tcbitem[title={Join}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg? : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $<$ max\\
items' = items$\overset{\smallfrown}{ }\langle$ msg? $\rangle$  
%
\tcbitem[title={Leave}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg! : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $\ne \langle \rangle$\\
items $= \langle\text{msg!}\rangle\overset{\smallfrown}{ }$items'  
%
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, title={\textsc{Init}}] items $=\langle\ \rangle$
%
\tcbitem[title={Join}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg? : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $<$ max\\
items' = items$\overset{\smallfrown}{ }\langle$ msg? $\rangle$  
%
\tcbitem[title={Leave}]
$\Delta$(items)\\
msg! : MSG
\tcblower
\#items $\ne \langle \rangle$\\
items $= \langle\text{msg!}\rangle\overset{\smallfrown}{ }$items' 
%
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2, title={\textsc{Init}}] items $=\langle\ \rangle$ 
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a combination of box drawing characters like `│─┌├└` and `\obeyspaces`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\begin{document}
\obeyspaces\noindent%
┌──\textit{Buffer}──────────────────────────────────────────────────────\\
│   $\upharpoonright$(\textit{max}, \textsc{Init}, \textit{Join, Leave})\\
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────\\
│  │  \textit{max :} $\mathbb{N}$\\
│  │  \textit{items :} seq \textit{MSG}\\
│  ├──────────────\\
│  │  \textit{\#items} $\leqslant$ \textit{max}\\
│  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────\\
│  ┌──\textsc{Init}───────────────────────────────────────────────\\
│  │  \textit{items} $=\langle\ \rangle$\\
│  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────\\
│  ┌──\textit{Join}───────────────────  ┌──\textit{Leave}───────────────────\\
│  │  $\Delta$(\textit{items})                        \hskip4.7pt│  $\Delta$(\textit{items})\\
│  │  \textit{msg? : MSG}                   \hskip4pt│  \textit{msg! : MSG}\\
│  ├────────                          \hskip4.8pt├────────\\
│  │  \textit{\#items} $<$ \textit{max}                 \hskip2.3pt│  \textit{\#items} $\ne\langle\ \rangle$\\
│  │  $\mathit{items}' = \mathit{items} \overset{\smallfrown}{ }\langle\mathit{msg?}\rangle$      \hskip4pt│  $\mathit{items} = \langle\mathit{msg!}\rangle\overset{\smallfrown}{ }\mathit{items}'$\\
│  └─────────────────────────  └──────────────────────────\\
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────\\
\end{document}
```

The original is probably made with a package though, to calculate the various indents. I don't know which package that would be unfortunately :)

[image]

Comment: Wow this is perfect, I didn't know box drawing characters were a thing. Thanks!

Comment: Well I wouldn't recommend doing this by hand because it is a lot of work :)